# How can I redirect to another page using testcafe after logging with TestCafe

Tags: authentication, testing, automated-tests, vpn, testcafe

I am trying to redirect to another page after a login with testCafe, but after the login that other page remains blank, that is, it never loads, or at other times it simply closes the session without entering. The fact is that it does not let me go to the main page after login. I use a VPN connection. Do you know what it could be, a login token or VPN problem? How can I solve it?

This my code

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { Role } from 'testcafe'

const role = Role('login_page', async t => {
    await t
      .wait(10000)

      .click(Selector('button.btn.btn-dark.btn-lg.btn-block'))
      .typeText('input[name="loginfmt"]', 'my_user')
      .pressKey('enter')
      .typeText('input[name="Password"]', 'my_password')
      .click('span[id="submitButton"]')
      .click('input[id="idSIButton9"]')

}, { preserveUrl: true });

fixture `My Fixture`;

test('My test', async t => {
    await t
        .navigateTo('home_page_after_login')
        .useRole(role);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be navigating to the 'home_page_after_login' page before actually logging in.

Could you try this?

```
test('My test', async t => {
    await t
        .useRole(role);
        .navigateTo('home_page_after_login')
        
});
```

Also, there was a known issue in 'Roles' module.  So, you might have to use a 'wait' after clicking 'login' button.

```
const role = Role('login_page', async t => {
    await t
      .wait(10000)
      .click(Selector('button.btn.btn-dark.btn-lg.btn-block'))
      .typeText('input[name="loginfmt"]', 'my_user')
      .pressKey('enter')
      .typeText('input[name="Password"]', 'my_password')
      .click('span[id="submitButton"]')
      .click('input[id="idSIButton9"]')
      .wait(5000)

}, { preserveUrl: true });
```

Comment: Yes i try this too, but not working.
Its probably my page generate a token, but idk how to save this for run the other test.

Comment: To isolate the problem, could you try without using 'Role' and by directly using the login steps within the test please?  If it fails, there would atleast be some kind of debug logs which would help progress further.  I have used Testcafe for websites inside VPN and it was able to handle the login steps fine.  I am not sure on the token generation part though.

Comment: yes i try too, and i use similar code in selenium and its works, but idk what happened is probably testcafe don't save the cookie or the connection is lost with the server